# Numpy insert rows to match number of max row count

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have the following array:

```
a = [[40.5,  23.4],
     [175.9, 20.2],
     [21.4,  24.0],
     [130.3, 18.4],
     [6.3,   25.7],
     [73.4,  21.5],
     [16.6,  25.7],
     [125.9, 19.1],
     [41.4,  24.7],
     [180.6, 16.4],
     [13.6,  24.4],
     [103.2, 19.0],
     [3.2,   24.7],
     [55.9,  23.1],
     [208.8, 20.4]]
```

I need to add rows with zeroes to have the final array as:

```
 b = [[40.5,  23.4],
      [175.9, 20.2],
      [0.,    0.],
      [21.4,  24.0],
      [130.3, 18.4],
      [0.,    0.],
      [6.3,   25.7],
      [73.4,  21.5],
      [0.,    0.],
      [16.6,  25.7],
      [125.9, 19.1],
      [0.,    0.],
      [41.4,  24.7],
      [0.,    0.],
      [0.,    0.],
      [180.6, 16.4],
      [0.,    0.],
      [0.,    0.],
      [13.6,  24.4],
      [103.2, 19.0],
      [0.,    0.],
      [3.2,   24.7],
      [55.9,  23.1],
      [208.8, 20.4]]
```

In Summary, what I need is to add rows to specific indexes however the number of rows is not constant. In this example (please see image), I need to add the number of rows that will make each key match the maximum number of keys. I don't care about the keys in my code but I need to somehow "normalise" the array so I'll have the same number of rows for each key.

[Array Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CBgX.png)

Here's a sample of the list of indices: `[[ 2 1] [ 4 1] [ 6 1] [ 8 2] [ 9 2] [10 1] [12 0]]`

I've tried np.insert, np.concatenate, advanced indexing, etc but could not come up with a solution.

Any Ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

# as it seems to me indeces you provided don't conform to the data, 
# here is just an example list of indeces. Substitute.
# First I transform this list to a form that can be fed to np.insert()
indeces = [[0, 2], [2, 3]] 
tmp = [[_[0]] * _[1] for _ in indeces]
indeces_flat = []
for elem in tmp:
    for item in elem:
        indeces_flat.append(item)
print(indeces_flat)
# substitute with your array
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
# the main insertion
a_inserted = np.insert(a, indeces_flat, [0, 0], axis=0)
print(a_inserted)
```

prints:

```
[0, 0, 2, 2, 2]
[[0 0]
 [0 0]
 [1 2]
 [3 4]
 [0 0]
 [0 0]
 [0 0]
 [5 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a NumPy based approach

```
def insert_n_zeros_at(a, i):
    # which zeros have more than 1 row inserted?
    m = i[:,1]>1
    #empty nan array, filled on cols >1 with replicated values
    ix = np.full((i.shape[0], i[:,1].max()),np.nan)
    ix[:,:1] = i[:,:1]
    ix.ravel()[np.stack((m,m)).ravel('F')] = np.repeat(i[m,0], i[m,1])
    # columns' values cumulative sum (they are the real indices)
    ix += np.arange(ix.shape[1])
    # accounts for the index increasement when prior rows are added
    cs = i[:,1].cumsum()
    ix[1:] += cs[:-1,None]
    # flattens to 1d of actual indices
    ix = ix[~np.isnan(ix)]
    # amount of zeros to insert. Used to define out
    out = np.zeros((a.shape[0]+cs[-1], a.shape[1]))
    r = np.arange(out.shape[0])
    # assign a where we don't have indices of 0s
    out[r[~np.isin(r, ix)]] = a
    return out
```

For the shared example, we get:

```
i = np.array([[ 2, 1], [ 4, 1], [ 6, 1], [ 8, 2], [ 9, 2], [10, 1]])

insert_n_zeros_at(a, i)
array([[ 40.5,  23.4], # 0
       [175.9,  20.2], # 1
       [  0. ,   0. ], # <- 1 zero at 2
       [ 21.4,  24. ], # 2
       [130.3,  18.4], # 3
       [  0. ,   0. ], # <- 1 zero at 4
       [  6.3,  25.7], # 4
       [ 73.4,  21.5], # 5
       [  0. ,   0. ], # <- 1 zero at 6
       [ 16.6,  25.7], # 6
       [125.9,  19.1], # 7
       [  0. ,   0. ], # <- 2 zeros at 8
       [  0. ,   0. ], 
       [ 41.4,  24.7], # 8
       [  0. ,   0. ], # <- 2 zeros at 9
       [  0. ,   0. ],
       [180.6,  16.4], # 9
       [  0. ,   0. ], # <- 1 zero at 10
       [ 13.6,  24.4], # 10
       [103.2,  19. ], # 11
       [  3.2,  24.7], # 12
       [ 55.9,  23.1], # 13
       [208.8,  20.4]])
```

Comment: Hey @yatu, your suggestion worked fine with the example array (a) I provided however if  I have a different array, I'm getting the following msg: `ix.ravel()[np.stack((m,m)).ravel('F')] = np.repeat(i[m,0], i[m,1])

IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 32 but corresponding boolean dimension is 16`. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Maciek, Thank you for the reply. I've tested your solution but it does not work when I have the `i = np.array([[ 2, 1], [ 4, 1], [ 6, 1], [ 8, 2], [ 9, 2], [10, 1]])` above. It gives me a shape mismatch error.

Comment: @Neyls: "works for me", I just run it with indeces = [[ 2, 1], [ 4, 1], [ 6, 1], [ 8, 2], [ 9, 2], [10, 1]] and it works fine. Of course, you have to extend the `a` array, because currently it has three rows only, so you can't refer to the 10th index. I made a solution on examplary data, becase the one you posted did not conform to what you had written. At the same time, I think my solution is really more readable than the one you accepted...
Try substituting `a` and `indeces` in my code with your data and see.

Comment: @Maciek: Thank you for the reply. I ended up using your solution. It works just fine for any size of array I throw at it.

Comment: Cool, this is what I wanted it to do!